# How do you run a BigQuery query and store the results in a table on a regular basis

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery view which takes about 30 seconds to run. I want to, once a day at a designated time, run the view and store the results in a materialized table (e.g. so that Data Studio dashboards can use the table without making the dashboard take 30 seconds to load)

Is there a built-in way to do this using a tool like dataproc, or do you have to just set up a cronjob that just runs

```sql
CREATE TABLE dataset.materialized_view AS
SELECT *
FROM dataset.view;
```

on a regular basis?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using [scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries).

In the [Classic BigQuery UI](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com) (Cloud Console UI support is under development at the time of this writing), write the query that you want to run in the "Compose Query" text area, then click the "Schedule Query" button. From the panel that appears, you can choose the frequency with which to run the query; the default is every 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a regular cron job which runs the query to read data from you view and write it to a destination table. Based on your example, something like:

```
bq --location=[LOCATION] query -n 0 --destination_table dataset.materialized_view --use_legacy_sql=false --replace=true 'select * from dataset.view'
```